# Mollification of a function continuous on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, need uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution, uniform-convergence

We know that if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then its mollification $f_\epsilon$ converges uniformly to $f$ on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

My question is, suppose $f$ is continuous everywhere except at $0$ (it blows up to infinity).

Is it possible to find a sequence via mollifcation $f_\epsilon$ such that $f_\epsilon$ converges to $f$ uniformly in the compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that don't contain $0$?

Comment: Yes, choose mollifiers $\varphi_\varepsilon$ with compact support $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mollification with $\phi_n\in C^\infty_0$ functions will do that, since the support will shrink with increasing $n$. Hence the domain of influence of a mollifier at a certain point different from the origin will be contained in a compact set not containing $0$.

Comment: Suppose we use the mollifier with support in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ as DanielFischer suggested. We want to to estimate $|f_\epsilon(x) - f(x)| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x-y)-f(x)|\phi_{\epsilon}(y)dy$. Consider the point $x= \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then we are integrating $|f(0.5\epsilon - y)-f(0.5)|\phi_{\epsilon}(y)|$ over $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. So $0.5\epsilon - y$ goes from $(-0.5\epsilon, 1.5\epsilon)$, and $f$ is unbounded on this domain. Isn't this a problem even if the mollifier has compact support?

Comment: @riem You asked for uniform convergence on compact sets in $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$. That is, you choose the compact set (first), which then has positive distance to the origin, and then look at the sequence with $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$. In particular, if $\varepsilon$ is small enough, the distance to the origin for any $x$ in the chosen compact set will be more than $\varepsilon$. Once the compact set has been chosen, you cannot choose $x$ arbirtrarily close to $0$ (like $\varepsilon/2$).